# Django Admin page Glitch

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-admin

Recently, in the last two projects the home page of the admin url in django appears with the following css glitch.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAWCT.png)

As I have done everything in the same way as the previous project I don't know why this is happening.
Is this a recent bug with the newer versions?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wQ5I.png)

Here is my settings.py:

```
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production


# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://127.0.0.1:5173",
]

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # External
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
    # Internal Apps
    'todo',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = "backend.urls"

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = "backend.wsgi.application"


# Database


DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.sqlite3",
        "NAME": BASE_DIR / "db.sqlite3",
    }
}


# Password validation


AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator",
    },
]


# Internationalization


LANGUAGE_CODE = "en-us"

TIME_ZONE = "UTC"

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)


STATIC_URL = "static/"

# Default primary key field type


DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = "django.db.models.BigAutoField"
```

and also the admin.py:

```
`from django.contrib import admin
from . import models

# Register your models here.

admin.site.register(models.Todo)`
```

I tried to install the libraries again and start a new project but this glitch keeps on hapenning

Comment: looks like version `4.2` has an issue. [Reference](https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/help-django-4-2-admin-page-css-issue/20196)